# How to load a another component after clicking a button using Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am creating an app, however, I want that when I click Signup, register() executes and upon return of a promise I want to route to the login route.

Instead of staying on the same signup page, I want to route to the login page

```
register(){

  axios.post('url', {

    username: this.username,
    password:this.password
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Are you using `vue-router`?

Comment: @BertEvans..Yes I am using vue-router

Answer (score 2):

Use `push()` on the router.

```
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  this.$router.push('login');
})
```

Vue-router has [programmatic navigation](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

Comment: Can i export router so I can use it in another component?

Comment: @Artwell $router is avaliable on *all* components.

Comment: @BertEvans is correct. And to answer your question, yes, you can also export it to use in another component. Here is an example... https://github.com/theosherman/insulin-calculator/blob/master/src/router/index.js